# SQL Server: specify blanket schema for OPENJSON to make all key value pairs column cell entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, json

One record in my database table is a JSON string with over 100 key/value pairs. I'm aware I can do the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(KEY_NAME_HERE VARCHAR(1000),KEY_NAME_HERE VARCHAR(1000),KEY_NAME_HERE VARCHAR(1000))
```

and just go on naming every key in the JSON object. Is there not a way to blanket every key in the JSON object with a default type so I don't have to enter every single key in the WITH clause? Something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(WILDCARD VARCHAR(1000))
```

I have tried grabbing the default json table and pivoting but ran into similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this dynamically.
I tried the following:

```
declare @json nvarchar(4000) = N'{  
   "SomeVal1":"John",  
   "SomeVal2":45,  
   "SomeVal3":true,  
   "SomeVal4":false
}'

declare @sql nvarchar(max), @params nvarchar(100), @keys nvarchar(max) 

set @params = N'@json nvarchar(4000), @keys nvarchar(max)';  
select @keys = stuff(( select distinct ', ' + cast([key] as nvarchar(1000)) + ' nvarchar(1000) '  [text()]
                       from (select * from openjson(@json)) t 
                       for xml path(''), type)
                       .value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,' ') 
                      from ( select * from openjson(@json) ) t
--debug
select @keys as keys
set @sql =  'select * from openjson(@json) with (' + @keys + ')'

--debug
select @sql as [generated query]

execute sp_executesql @sql, @params, @json = @json, @keys = @keys;
```

For some reason, I could not make it work so that also the `@keys` was parametrized in the `sp_executesql` call by adding it to the params definition, but like this it works.
Whether you can or you cannot execute `dynamic sql` in your scenario, that is another question.

Good luck!